# Popup to edit table contents

Tags: javascript

I'm working with tables, and want to make them editable in nice way.
I've the below `working` code that make cells editable:

```
//--->make div editable > start 
    document.querySelectorAll('.row_data').forEach(field =>
        field.addEventListener("click", function(event)
        {
            event.preventDefault(); 

            if(this.getAttribute('edit_type') == 'button')
            {
                return false; 
            }

            //make div editable
            this.closest('div').setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
            //add bg css
            this.classList.add('bg-warning');
            this.style.padding = '5px';

            this.focus();
        })
    );  
//--->make div editable > end
```

And below `working` table that update the field after editing it:

```js
//--->save single field data > start
    document.querySelectorAll('.row_data').forEach(field =>
        field.addEventListener("focusout", function(event)
        {
            event.preventDefault();

            if(this.getAttribute('edit_type') == 'button')
            {
                return false; 
            }

            var row_id = this.closest('tr').getAttribute('row_id'); 

            var row_div = this;             
            row_div.classList.remove('bg-warning') //add bg css
            row_div.style.padding='';

            var col_name = row_div.getAttribute('col_name'); 
            var col_val = row_div.innerHTML; 

            var arr = {};
            arr[col_name] = col_val;

            //use the "arr" object for your ajax call
            Object.assign(arr, {row_id:row_id});
            //out put to show
            document.querySelector(".post_msg").innerHTML = '<pre class="bg-success">'+JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2) +'</pre>';

        })
//--->save single field data > end
```

Instead of clicking the cell itself and editing it, I want a popup input field in the same location of the field to be edited to be poped up, then the pop up to be disappeared, and the field to be updated upon moving the cursor away, something like the below image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it with [custom-elements](https://javascript.info/custom-elements), as below but still need to work the CSS of the `slave`:

```
class MyInput extends HTMLElement {
    master = document.createElement('input');
    slave = document.createElement('input');

    constructor() {
      // Always call super first in constructor
      super();
      let self = this;   // Using `self` to avoid confusion among many `this` used

      // Create a shadow root
      const shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});


      self.master.setAttribute('class', 'master');

      self.slave.style.display = 'none';
      self.slave.setAttribute('class', 'slave');

    if (self.hasAttribute('data-text')) {
        self.value = `${self.getAttribute('data-text')}`;
    } else {
        self.value = '';
    }

    self.master.value = self.value;

    self.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        // Here `this` is for `self` itself 
        this.slave.style.display = '';
        this.slave.value = this.value;
        this.master.style.display = 'none';
        this.slave.focus();
      });

    ['focusout','keydown'].forEach( function(evt) {
        self.slave.addEventListener(evt, function(event) {
            // Here `this` is for the slave, i.e. `self.slave`
            if ((event.type === 'keydown' && event.which === 27) || event.type === 'focusout') {
                this.style.display = 'none';
                this.parentNode.querySelector('.master').style.display = '';
                this.parentNode.querySelector('.master').value = this.value;
                console.log('out');
            }
        }, false);
    });


 /*  self.slave.addEventListener("focusout", function(event) {
           this.style.display = 'none';
           this.parentNode.querySelector('.master').style.display = '';
           this.parentNode.querySelector('.master').value = this.value;
      })
      self.slave.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
         if (event.which === 27) {  // Esc
                this.style.display = 'none';
                this.parentNode.querySelector('.master').style.display = '';
            }
      })
*/

      // Apply external styles to the shadow dom
      const linkElem = document.createElement('link');
      linkElem.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
      linkElem.setAttribute('href', 'my-input.css');
      // Create some CSS to apply to the shadow dom
      const style = document.createElement('style');
      console.log(style.isConnected);

    style.textContent = `
      .master {
            width: '10px';
        }
        .slave {
            width: '15px';
            color: yellow;
            background-color: blue;
        }
     `;

      // Attach the created element to the shadow dom
      shadow.appendChild(linkElem);
    //  shadow.appendChild(style);
    // Attach the created elements to the shadow dom
      shadow.appendChild(this.master);
      shadow.appendChild(this.slave);
    }

   get value(){ return this.entry; }
   set value(val) { console.log(`got = ${val}`); this.entry = val}
}

// Define the new element
customElements.define('my-input', MyInput);
//customElements.define('my-input', MyInput, { extends: "input" });
```

And called it as:

```
<tr><td><my-input data-text="fname"></my-input></td><td><my-input data-text="lname"></my-input></td></tr>
```

And the CSS which needs to be improved is:

```css
.master {
    width: '10px';
}
.slave {
    width: '15px';
    color: yellow;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```js
class MyInput extends HTMLElement {
    master = document.createElement('input');
    slave = document.createElement('input');

    constructor() {
      // Always call super first in constructor
      super();
      let self = this;   // Using `self` to avoid confusion among many `this` used
  
      // Create a shadow root
      const shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});

      
      self.master.setAttribute('class', 'master');
      
      self.slave.style.display = 'none';
      self.slave.setAttribute('class', 'slave');

    if (self.hasAttribute('data-text')) {
        self.value = `${self.getAttribute('data-text')}`;
    } else {
        self.value = '';
    }

    self.master.value = self.value;

    self.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        // Here `this` is for `self` itself 
        this.slave.style.display = '';
        this.slave.value = this.value;
        this.master.style.display = 'none';
        this.slave.focus();
      });

 /*   ['focusout','keydown'].forEach( function(evt) {
        self.slave.addEventListener(evt, function(event) {
            // Here `this` is for the slave, i.e. `self.slave`
            if ((event.type === 'keydown' && event.which === 27) || event.type === 'focusout') {
                this.style.display = 'none';
                this.parentNode.querySelector('.master').style.display = '';
                this.parentNode.querySelector('.master').value = this.value;
                console.log('out');
            }
        }, false);
    });
*/

      self.slave.addEventListener("focusout", function(event) {
           this.style.display = 'none';
           this.parentNode.querySelector('.master').style.display = '';
           this.parentNode.querySelector('.master').value = this.value;
      })
      self.slave.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
         if (event.which === 27) {  // Esc
                this.style.display = 'none';
                this.parentNode.querySelector('.master').style.display = '';
            }
      })

      
      // Apply external styles to the shadow dom
    //  const linkElem = document.createElement('link');
    //  linkElem.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
    //  linkElem.setAttribute('href', 'my-input.css');
      // Create some CSS to apply to the shadow dom
      const style = document.createElement('style');
      console.log(style.isConnected);
  
    style.textContent = `
      .master {
            width: '10px';
        }
        .slave {
            width: '15px';
            color: yellow;
            background-color: blue;
        }
     `;

      // Attach the created element to the shadow dom
    //  shadow.appendChild(linkElem);
      shadow.appendChild(style);
      // Attach the created elements to the shadow dom
      shadow.appendChild(this.master);
      shadow.appendChild(this.slave);
    }

   get value(){ return this.entry; }
   set value(val) { console.log(`got = ${val}`); this.entry = val}
}
  
// Define the new element
customElements.define('my-input', MyInput);
//customElements.define('my-input', MyInput, { extends: "input" });
```

```css
.master {
    width: '10px';
}
.slave {
    width: '15px';
    color: yellow;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead><tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th></tr></thead>
    <tr><td is='my-cell' data-text="fname"></td><td is='my-cell' data-text="lname"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><my-input data-text="fname"></my-input></td><td><my-input data-text="lname"></my-input></td></tr>
</table>
```